# Ext Js code to create a form not working

Tags: forms, extjs, combobox

Below is the code for creating a simple form. It is not working. Any solutions?

[Sample form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euRO0.png)

Nothing is showing when I run this code.

```
   Ext.onReady(function(){
   Ext.QuickTips.init();
var simple=new Ext.FormPanel({
    lableWidth:75,
    frame:true,
url:'save-form.php',
title:'Login',
  bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
   width: 350,
   defaults:{width: 230},
    defaultType:'textfield',
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    items:[
    {
        fieldLabel: 'username',
        name:'Username',
        id:'user',
        allowBlank:false
    },
    {
        fieldLabel:'password',
        name:'Password',
        id:'pass',
        allowBlank:false,
        inputType:'password'
    },
    {
        xtype:'combobox',
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
        {
            fields:['abbr','name'],
            data:[
            {
                'abbr':'dev',
                'name':'Developer'
            },
            {
                'abbr':'test',
                'name':'tester'
            }]

        }),
        displayField:'name',
        emptyText:'Select user type..'
    },
    {
        fieldLabel:'Email',
        name:'Email',
        allowBlank:false,
        vtype:'email'
    },
    {
        boxLabel:'Remember me',
        xtype:'checkbox'
    }],

    buttons:[
    {
        text:'Login',
        handler:function()
        {
            var a=Ext.getCmp('user').getValue();
            var b=Ext.getCmp('pass').getValue();
            if(a=="saturn"&&b=="saturn")
                alert('Succesfull');
            else
                alert('id and password missmatch');
            simple.getForm().reset();
        }
    }]
})
simple.render(document.body);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css">      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script> 
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You could explain what you expect to see, show console logs, try debugging etc to give us a bit more to go on. As it is you are unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: Your fiddle is about combobox, where is the form in that. Place your form code and run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You have used **fieldset** in form directly if you want to use this then add inside **items** of form. Please refer [ExtJs Docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.form.FieldSet.html)

I have created an demo hope it will help you. [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26vm)

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Form',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    lableWidth: 75,
    frame: true,
    url: 'save-form.php',
    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: '80%',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        padding: 20,
        defaults: {
            width: '100%',
            flex: 1
        },
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'username',
            name: 'Username',
            id: 'user',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'password',
            name: 'Password',
            id: 'pass',
            allowBlank: false,
            inputType: 'password'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
                data: [{
                    'abbr': 'dev',
                    'name': 'Developer'
                }, {
                    'abbr': 'test',
                    'name': 'tester'
                }]

            }),
            displayField: 'name',
            emptyText: 'Select user type..'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Email',
            name: 'Email',
            allowBlank: false,
            vtype: 'email'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Remember me',
            xtype: 'checkbox'
        }],
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Login',
        formBind: true,
        handler: function () {
           //your login here
           Ext.Msg.alert('Success','You have clicked on Login...!');
        }
    }]
});
```